# Charging problem

Tags: electrical, motorcycle, charging, ducati, voltage-regulator

Ducati 450 scrambler 1975 converted to 12v with Luas Rita AB11 electronic ignition it is so easy to start with this modification I put a new original alternator 3 face that gives up to 55v at 5000rpm a new original reg/rec output 14v and the problem it is not charging the battery do you think that I have to do a diode after the battery or something?

Thank and I appreciate for help.

Comment: If I was you, I would get a cheap voltage gauge (or multimeter), hook it up to the battery, and rev it up to a normal riding RPM. The gauge *should* read between 13.5-14.0.

Comment: Also, you might find [this guide](https://thegsresources.com/statorpapers4.php) helpful for troubleshooting. It is for Suzuki GS bikes from the same time as your bike (I have a '79 gs850). Though the exact voltages for your bike may differ, it gives you a very good idea of what *should* be happening

Answer (score 1):

So a “new original” alternator - 6v or 12v..

You put a 12v ignition system so the battery needs to be 12v and so does the alternator and the regulator.

If those things are mis- matched then they won’t work, it seems lucky that it runs.